# how to change state of 1 out of 3 components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following layout.

```
<ParentComponent>
  |ComponentA
  |ComponentA
  |ComponentA
```

Basically I call the same Component 3 times in the parent component because they are very similar but just have different values. I was told I need to put a button on the parent component to change the values of just one out of the 3 ComponentA. ComponentA is called 3 times to give me the same thing 3 times, if I make a button to set the state of one, it will go to all 3. How can I single out one component?

Thanks!

Comment: Share code what you tried

Comment: Just pass a prop to the first component, and don't pass the same prop, or don't pass the same value, to the other 2.

Comment: @Ronak07 Im not sure if I am allowed to share the code and really dont want to get in trouble for it. What I have done so far is pass props to each one to give them each separate values. I was asked to make a button in the parent component to change the value of just one of the 3 components.

Comment: @TKoL that is exactly what I did. I passed props to each one individually. Now I was told to make a button to change the value of those props in one of the 3 components. I have looked online but cant seem to find how to do this.

Comment: try a unique `key` : `<ComponentA key="1" /> <ComponentA key="2" /> ...`

Comment: @Taki could you further expand on what they key would do? I could assign a button to the component with the key?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of props you want to send to your components, and then change the content of that array on some button/input events, as your application demands it.

For example:

```
const arrOfProps = [{someProp:'aaa'}, null, null]

const someFunc = (num)=>{
    arrOfProps.forEach((x, index)=>{
        if (index === num) {x = {someProp:'aaa'}}
        else { x = null}
    })
}

render(){
    return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>someFunc(0)}>One</button>
        <button onClick={()=>someFunc(1)}>Two</button>
        <button onClick={()=>someFunc(2)}>Three</button>
        <ParentComponent>
            <div>{arrOfComponents.map((comp, index)=>{
                return <ComponentA key={index} prop={comp}/>
            })}</div>
        </ParentComponent>
    </div>)
}
```